# Ajax Php dependent dropdown select - How to post name of city instead id into database (submit from data)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Few days I try to solve problem but no luck.
Problem is next:

- Web form with dependent dropdown select box where user can select his
  city, zip and street and that work but.
- When I submit form in my database no `city_name` (text) - only `city_id` (number/value).

So, question is - How to post `city_name` in database? User is from Rome and I Rome (text) is submited not `city_id` (number).

Select input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grad">City:*</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="999">---Enter city yourself---</option>
                    <?php $sql_query="SELECT * FROM city_table order by city_id asc";
                          $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
                          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['city_id'].'_'.$row['city_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['city_name'];?></option>
                    <?php }?>
                </select>
       </div>
</div>


<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="post_no">ZIP code:*</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select name="zip_name" id="zip_name" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="recalculate_price();">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="address">Street:*</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select name="street_name" id="street_name" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="recalculate_price();">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

get_zip_php

```
<?php
include('db_config.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM zip_table where city_id='$id' order by zip_name asc";
 $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
 ?>
 <option selected="selected">Select ZIP code :</option><?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['zip_id']; ?>-<?php echo $row['limousine']; ?>-<?php echo $row['kombi']; ?>-<?php echo $row['mini_van']; ?>"><?php echo $row['zip_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
 }
}
?>
```

get_street_php

```
<?php
include('db_config.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $sql_query="SELECT * FROM street_table where zip_id='$id' order by street_name asc";
 $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
 ?>
 <option selected="selected">Select street please :</option><?php
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['street_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['street_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
 }
}
?>
```

Ajax:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#city_name").change(function()
     {
      var id=$(this).val();
      var data = 'id='+ id;

      $.ajax
      ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "get_zip.php",
       data: data,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html)
        {
            $("#zip_name").html(html);
            recalculate_price();
        } 
    });
});


$("#zip_name").change(function()
    {
      var id=$(this).val();
      var data = 'id='+ id;

      $.ajax
      ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "get_street.php",
       data: data,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html)
       {
        $("#street_name").html(html);
        recalculate_price();
       } 
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

If I make some changes on "select city part" (I`m beginner and really I`m lost in all this) I can`t pass zip.

So, please tell me where to make all changes to pass all that things and post `city_name`, zip (name...I make it as "xxxx - city") and street name. Please help me, I googled and read here about problems few days and can`t continue work on my project until I fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: concatenate the id with value like this using delimiter like this <option value="<?php echo $row['city_id'].'_'.$row['city_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['city_name'];?></option>

Comment: Thanks jothi but is possible remove number (id) somehow from 6_Rome and post only Rome?

Comment: in php  use $ss = explode('_','6_Rome');  like this and print_r($ss);  echo $ss[0];

Comment: look this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: if you want split this jquery use var res = varibale_name.split("_");

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do that here, we prefer that the solution is added below, rather than as a question addendum. If you simply just wish to thank poster(s) who helped you, consider accepting a best answer (by clicking the adjacent tick mark so it turns green) or upvoting any good answers (by clicking the adjacent up arrow). This is how we thank people on _Stack Overflow_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bellow select tag. It may useful for you

```
<select type="text" name="city_name" id="city_name" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="999">---Enter city yourself---</option>
    <?php 
        $sql_query="SELECT * FROM city_table order by city_id asc";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo  "<option value='".$row['city_id']."'>".$row['city_name']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but... i have same select options on this way <option value="6">Rome</option> and again on submit "6" will be submited not "Rome".

Comment: by default only value will get submit. If you want to store your option(text) to db then use var cname=$("#city_name option:selected").text(); it will return selected option text. store cname into your db

Comment: where to use (part of my code) this var cname=$("#city_name option:selected").text(); or how to include it? Thanks.

Comment: post complete code include html javascript and php then I will let you know  where to add.

Comment: @ Phaneendra Kasalanati posted

Comment: In your php where sql is building use $cname=explode('_',$_POST['city_name'])[1]; and insert with $cname as your city name. Then city name will insert into database.

Comment: Not understand well. Where to use var cname=$("#city_name option:selected").text();? And $cname=explode('_',$_POST['city_name'])[1]; need to use on my action page or...? On action page is: $city_name=trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city_name'])); What is sintax for explode and trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city_name'])); ? Thanks for help.

Comment: In your action page instaed of trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city_name'])); use trim(mysql_real_escape_string(explode('_',$_POST['city_name'])[1])); then city name will insert into database

Comment: I don`t have enough reputation to make your answer as useful. I will post solved solution in my OP edit. Thank you Phaneendra Kasalanati.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the id with value like this using delimiter like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['city_id'].'_'.$row['city_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['city_name'];?></option>
```

In php use `explode()`

The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

```
    $ss = explode('_','6_Rome'); 

    print_r($ss); 

    echo $ss[0];  //6 pass the value into query
```

In jquery use `split()`

Split a string into an array of substrings:
        use split()

```
    $vv = variable_name.split("_");
```

Answer (score -1):

fetch city name from database on the basis of city id in your POST array before INSERT Query.

```
SELECT `city_name` FROM `city_table` WHERE `city_id`='".$_POST['city_name']."'
```

then use that city name in your insert query.

Comment: How to fetch it before query? Sorry but can you explain me please. If i use this SELECT no cities at all.

Comment: you have to use this query after submitting form in your action page