# PHP / Ajax how to filter products by category name

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have two dropdown list, one at the top is the category of meals, when I select one I have the id_cat in my option tag

```
              <option value="1">Pâtisserie</option>
              <option value="2">Pain & spéciaux</option>
```

The second dropdown is the list of the product.

When I choose one category, **I want to change product related to this id_cat with ajax...**

I tried but I don't have any idea how to do this

```
  <li>
    <label for="cat">Catégorie :</label>
    <select id="cat" name="cat">
      <?php foreach($cats as $cat): ?>
        <option value="<?= $cat['id_cat'] ?>"><?= $cat['nom_cat'] ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="meal">Nom :</label>
    <select id="meal" name="meal">
      <?php foreach($meals as $meal): ?>
        <option value="<?= $meal['Id'] ?>"><?= $meal['Name'] ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <article id="meal-details" class="meal-details no-left-label">
      <img src="" alt="Photo du produit">
      <p ></p>
      <span>Prix : <strong></strong> €</span>
    </article>
  </li>
```

My SQL query is simply

```
$sql = 'SELECT
                                    *
                            FROM meal
                            WHERE id_cat = ?';
```

Problem is how I can display products by category in my layout?

See screen here : https://ibb.co/LY4TDX5

Comment: on change you need to trigger an api call which by passing the selected value. Please post the minimal code so we can help you out

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917636/ajax-php-dependent-dropdown-select-how-to-post-name-of-city-instead-id-into-da

Comment: It's not what I want to do @Mohit Kumar

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery instead of plain JavaScript is ok...

First, create a listener for the category id at the bottom of the page (so dom is already loaded):

```
<script>
$(‘#cat’).on(‘change’, function() {
    loadMeals($(this).val() );
});
```

Now, do an Ajax call and put results in meals:

```
var url = ‘url_for_your_php_script’;
function loadMeals(category) {
    var response = $.post(
        url,
        { category: category}
     ).done( function (data) {
        $(‘#meal’).html(data);
    });
}

</script >
```

Your php script needs to do the query

```
select id, name from meal where id_cat=?
```

Usually, I recommend having the php script respond with json, but for simplicity of this answer, have it output the html for the options.

```
<?php foreach($meals as $meal): ?>
    <option value="<?= $meal['Id'] ?>"><?= $meal['Name'] ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

(kudos for concise, readable code)

Please note, this is typed out off the top of my head using my phone. You will want to double check how to do an Ajax post with jquery.